# Send parameters by onclick full calendar

Tags: javascript, php, fullcalendar

I am using full calendar. It is working fine. But I have problem to send parameters by onclick event. I have this js:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                    theme: true,
                    header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        editable: false,
                    minTime: 8,
                    maxTime: 21,
                    weekMode: 'liquid',

                    eventClick: function(start, end, allDay) { // Get the start, end, allday when one event slot is clicked

                            $('#time').val(start); // Set an hidden field with start value (String or Timestamp)
                            $('#hiddenEnd').val(end); // Set another hidden field with end value (String or Timestamp)
                            $('#hiddenAllDay').val(allDay); // Set another hidden field with allDay value (true or false)

                    },

        events: "<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/index.php/aula/calend/<?php echo $id; ?>",

                    eventRender: function (event, element) {
                        element.attr('href', 'javascript:void(0);');
                        element.attr('onclick', 'openModal("' + event.title + '","' + event.description + '","' + event.start + '");');
                    },

        eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
            alert(event.title + ' foi movido ' + delta + ' dia(s)\n' +
                '(Esta acao nao altera o banco de dados!)');
        },

        loading: function(bool) {
            if (bool) $('#loading').show();
            else $('#loading').hide();
        }

    });



});

    function openModal(title, info, start) {
        $("#eventInfo").html(info);
        $("#start-time").val(start);
        //var dd = start;
        $("#add-event").dialog({ modal: true, title: title, width:550,
        buttons: {
            "Salvar": function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url: "<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/index.php/aula/marcacao",
                    data: $('#add-event-form').serialize(),
                    success: function(){
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                    }
                });
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },

            Cancel: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },});
    };
```

When I click in one event, I need to send the hour for that event to php, because I need to use it in my query, before open dialog using this form:

```
<form action="" id ="add-event-form" name="add-event-form">

       <?php query = "SELECT aula FROM cursos WHERE hour = ****Hour clicked on calendar**** ?>

       <label for="title">Event Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="title" id="title"/>
    <p>
    <label for="add-date">Date</label>
    <input type="text" name="event-date" id="event-date" tabindex="-1" />
    </p>
    <p>
    <label for="add-start-time">Start Time</label>
    <input type="text" name="start-time" id="start-time" value=""/>
    </p>
    <p>
    <label for="add-end-time">End Time</label>
    <input type="text" name="end-time" id="end-time" />
    </p>
</form>
```

I have been trying to solve this for several days without success. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: You are missing a `$` here : `<?php query = "SELECT...` typo ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `eventClick: function(start, end, allDay)`, use eventClick: `function(event)`.
Then to access the variables use event.start, event.end, event.allDay. All you need to do then is match them with your query.

This is because eventClick does not take a start, end or allDay parameter but rather an event, jsEvent or view parameters. Source: [Official Documentation](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/mouse/eventClick/)

Answer (score 0):

Just use $_POST['start-time'] on the server side to retrieve the parameter.

```
$start = htmlspecialchars($_POST['start-time']);
$query = "SELECT aula FROM cursos WHERE hour =". $start;
```

Comment: He says that when he clicks a event he wants to send the hour, the onclick handler has a Ajax request that doesn't contain any parameters. What I'm missing?

Comment: `data:` is there for this. It sends an ajax request with all the form serialized. So you can get the hour with just `$_POST['start-time']`

Comment: Oops! Thank you, gonna delete this.

Comment: I appreciate answers. I tried it ($start = htmlspecialchars($_POST['start-time']);), but without success. Let me try explain more...Form (id ="add-event-form") is hidden. When i click one event of calendar, it shows this form. But, it does not send form yet...so when i try get by $_POST, it is null. I need to send by js value for hour that click in the calendar and pass it to php before show form. Can you understand me? I am sorry bad english and explanation. I hope you can understand. Thanks for all help!

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not send yet", try to see if that variable from the data atributte isn't null checking it on the console.

Comment: The input {<input type="text" name="start-time" id="start-time" value=""/>} receive value by {$("#start-time").val(start);}, but how can i get this? I can get it after submit this form...but i need get it before send form...in fact before render form. Can you understand?